# Is there any way to restore deleted omnibox suggestions?

Tags: google-chrome

Let's say I accidentally remove an omnibox suggestion on Chrome with the `SHIFT + DEL` combination. This also removes the site from my "most visited" list on the start page. Is there any way to undo both of these "events"? While clearly I could simply wait for the site in question to show up again (if I'm going to use it sufficiently frequently anyway), is there a faster way for this to be "resolved"?